# Showing that $C^1(D)\subseteq$ $locallyLipx(D)$ $\subseteq C(D)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, lipschitz-functions

Assume that $(t,x)$ $\in$ $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ $^n$ non-empty, open, and connected set, and that $f:D\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Prove that $C^1(D)\subseteq$ $\text{locallyLip}_x(D)$ $\subseteq C(D)$ with respect to $x$.

The definition of $\text{locallyLip}_x(D)$ is as follows:

$f(t,x)$ is locally Lipschitz on $D$ with respect to $x$, if for every $(t,x)\in D$, there exists an open set $U\in D$ with $(t,x)\in U$, such that $f$ is uniformly Lipschitz on $U$, with respect to $x$ on $D$.

I am only used to applying Lipschitz condition in the context of analysis or differential equations, and thus I am not sure I understand how to show these inclusions.

Comment: The core of the task is about the Lipschitz condition for differential equations. In ${\rm locallyLip}$ is missing that the function should be overall continuous. On the other hand, $C^1(D)$ implies local Lipschitz continuity in both arguments simultaneously. The needed claim is that if $f(t,x)$ is continuous and $\partial_xf(t,x)$ is continuous, then locally the conditions for Picard-Lindelöf are satisfied.

Comment: Do you also want $C(D)$ to mean continuous with respect to $x$?  Or must you deduce continuity in $(t,x)$ from only  locally lipschitz with respect to $x$?

Comment: For showing locallyLip_x $\subseteq C(D)$ I believe we must deduce continuity in $(t,x)$ from only locally lipschitz with respect to $x$.